# How to handle a search suggestion clicked item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contentprovider, search-suggestion

I used the officical Android sample code "SearchableDictionary" (Link: http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/index.html), that gives us a search interface, where you can search for a word and you have 2 options:

1- Put your keyword and click on search icon (keyboard), so a listview for all matched results will appear. You click on a word in the ListView to retrieve the definition.

2- Put your keyword and a little list of suggestion will appear automatically every time the searchView keyword changes, so you can click on a suggestion to retrieve her definition.

This is the code of the search function called when you click on an item in the big listview, not in the list of suggestions.

```
     private void doSearch(String queryStr) { 
            // get a Cursor, prepare the ListAdapter and set it
     final DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
     myDbHelper.openDataBase();
     Cursor cursor = managedQuery(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
             new String[] {queryStr}, null);
    //Cursor cursor = myDbHelper.fetchListItems(queryStr);
    //cursorr.moveToFirst(); // moves the cursor to the first row in the result set, returns false if the result set is empty.

    startManagingCursor(cursor); /* Managing cursors take care of closing the cursor when
    the activity is destroyed, but they do more than that as well: they will be
    deactivated and required as the activities is stopped and restarted. */

    // set the custom list adapter
    // setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, cursor));

     // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
     String[] from = new String[] { DataBaseHelper.KEY_WORD,
                                    DataBaseHelper.KEY_DEFINITION };

     // Specify the corresponding layout elements where we want the columns to go
     int[] to = new int[] { R.id.title,
                            R.id.details };

     // Create a simple cursor adapter for the definitions and apply them to the ListView
     SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                   R.layout.list_item_with_description, cursor, from, to);
     final ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
     mListView.setAdapter(words);
    // search_keyword = queryStr ;

     // Define the on-click listener for the list items
     mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


             // Build the Intent used to open WordActivity with a specific word Uri
             Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DefinitionActivity.class);
            // final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();


             Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                             String.valueOf(id));


             Log.d(TAG,"clicked row id="+id);

             wordIntent.setData(data);
             wordIntent.putExtra("clicked_item_id",id);

             startActivity(wordIntent);
         }
     });
```

As you can see we can handle the items clicked in the list of matched words, but how can i handle the suggestions clicked in the little list of suggestions? I want to catch the id of the clicked suggestion, not the clicked item in the big listview. How can I make this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a search suggestion is clicked, an Intent is sent to your searchable activity. You can simply define the Action field of this Intent though your searchable XML by configuring the android:searchSuggestIntentAction attribute like this:

```
<searchable 
...
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction = "android.intent.action.VIEW">
```

And then, in your searchable Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction()) {
    //a suggestion was clicked... do something about it...
}
```